# How to generate script data with PK and FK in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

i tried this one but i am not able to get the output.

Right Click on Your Database --> Select Task --> Generate Script --> Click Advanced --> Script for server version --> sql server_2008 --> types of data to script = schema and data --> Select Next in Script Wizard --> Select Script Entire Database --> finish.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the advanced option and set 'script primary keys' and 'script foreign keys option' to true..

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your Reply friend(Unnikrishnan R). I tried but final out put i was not getting properly

Comment: what is your issue in the result?

Comment: Final slide option Save or publish Script. From this option(Action Result two option is there. in that result showing error only.)if it's success then  we have to choose  FINISH option.

Comment: this error i am getting                                            System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlScriptPublish.GeneratePublishPage.worker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e) at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)

Comment: I think your data is large enough since you are pulling objects scripts with data..that why it is throwing this exception.. Try to split up the database objects and execute it separately..